# Remove actions/filters that are set with create_function()

Tags: filters, hooks, actions

This theme I was handed from another dev company is littered with `add_action/filter( 'hook/filter', create_function( '', 'return blah('blah')' );` We will be moving this site to a server running `php 7.2`.

I am wondering what's the appropriate method to remove these actions and filters. Or can I simply just copy and paste the /path/to/file in the child directory and know that this will be overwritten?

#### Here's an example

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'ot_register_theme_options_page' ) ) {

        function ot_register_theme_options_page() {

            /* get the settings array */
            $get_settings = _ut_theme_options();

            /* sections array */
            $sections = isset( $get_settings['sections'] ) ? $get_settings['sections'] : [];

            /* settings array */
            $settings = isset( $get_settings['settings'] ) ? $get_settings['settings'] : [];

            /* build the Theme Options */
            if ( function_exists( 'ot_register_settings' ) && OT_USE_THEME_OPTIONS ) {

                ot_register_settings(
                    [
                        [
                            'id'    => 'option_tree',
                            'pages' => [
                                [
                                    'id'              => 'ot_theme_options',
                                    'parent_slug'     => apply_filters( 'ot_theme_options_parent_slug', 'unite-welcome-page' ),
                                    'page_title'      => apply_filters( 'ot_theme_options_page_title', __( 'Theme Options', 'option-tree' ) ),
                                    'menu_title'      => apply_filters( 'ot_theme_options_menu_title', __( 'Theme Options', 'option-tree' ) ),
                                    'capability'      => $caps = apply_filters( 'ot_theme_options_capability', 'edit_theme_options' ),
                                    'menu_slug'       => apply_filters( 'ot_theme_options_menu_slug', 'ut_theme_options' ),
                                    'icon_url'        => apply_filters( 'ot_theme_options_icon_url', null ),
                                    'position'        => apply_filters( 'ot_theme_options_position', null ),
                                    'updated_message' => apply_filters( 'ot_theme_options_updated_message', __( 'Theme Options updated.', 'option-tree' ) ),
                                    'reset_message'   => apply_filters( 'ot_theme_options_reset_message', __( 'Theme Options reset.', 'option-tree' ) ),
                                    'button_text'     => apply_filters( 'ot_theme_options_button_text', __( 'Save Changes', 'option-tree' ) ),
                                    'screen_icon'     => 'themes',
                                    'sections'        => $sections,
                                    'settings'        => $settings,
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ]
                );

                // Filters the options.php to add the minimum user capabilities.
                add_filter( 'option_page_capability_option_tree', create_function( '$caps', "return '$caps';" ), 999 );

            }

        }

    }
```

I'm aware the appropriate `add_filter` would come out to being `add_filter( 'option_page_capability_option_tree', function($caps) { return $caps; }, 999);`

Comment: Note the deprecation warnings are because `create_function` is going to be removed in a future PHP version, that part has nothing to do with WordPress, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161526/php-7-2-function-create-function-is-deprecated

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove the hooks and filters, we need to be able to get a reference to the callable that was added, but in this case, `create_function` was used, so that's extremely difficult. It's also the reason you're getting deprecation notices. Sadly the only way to fix those deprecations is to change the parent theme to fix it.

#### Fixing The Deprecations

The PHP docs say that `create_function` works like this:

> ```
> string create_function ( string $args , string $code )
> ```
>
> Creates an anonymous function from the parameters passed, and returns a unique name for it.

And of note, `create_function` is deprecated in PHP 7.2

So this:

```
create_function( '$a', 'return $a + 1;' )
```

Becomes:

```
function( $a ) {
    return $a + 1;
}
```

Or even

```
function add_one( $a ) {
    return $a + 1;
}
```

This should eliminate the `create_function` calls, and turn the anonymous functions into normal calls that can be removed in a child theme

#### Removing The Hooks and Filters

Now that we've done that, we can now remove and replace them in the child theme.

To do this, we need 2 things:

- to run the removal code **after** they were added
- to be able to unhook the filters/actions

Putting your replacement in is easy, just use `add_filter` and `add_action`, but that adds your version, we need to remove the parent themes version.

Lets assume that this code is in the parent theme:

```
add_filter('wp_add_numbers_together' 'add_one' );
```

And that we want to replace it with a `multiply_by_two` function. First lets do this on the `init` hook:

```php
function nickm_remove_parent_hooks() {
    //
}
add_action('init', 'nickm_remove_parent_hooks' );
```

Then call `remove_filter and` add_filter`:

```php
function nickm_remove_parent_hooks() {
    remove_filter( 'wp_add_numbers_together' 'add_one' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'nickm_remove_parent_hooks' );
add_action( 'wp_add_numbers_together', 'multiply_by_two' );
```

Keep in mind that child themes let you override templates, but `functions.php` is not a template, and child themes don't change how `include` or `require` work. A child themes `functions.php` is loaded first, but otherwise, they're similar to plugins.

#### And Finally

You shouldn't be registering post types, roles, capabilities, and taxonomies in a theme, it's a big red flag and creates lock in, preventing data portability. These things are supposed to be in plugins, not themes

Comment: Unhooking these from WordPress filters and actions is not a generic PHP question.

Comment: @JacobPeattie you misunderstand, the OP doesn't want to unhook them, the OP wants to replace them with versions that don't generate deprecation warnings, that's what my answer does. Moving beyond my answer would involve generic PHP callable knowledge though, hence the final paragraph, it's not the job of this stack to explain how to write a PHP closure, and there are other questions and answers for how to use hooks and filters with classes etc

Comment: They asked about removing them from a child theme. So they'd need to unhook them to do that.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, re-read the original question, the OP wanted to add not remove, and the OP wanted to remove deprecation warnings in `debug.log`. How do they remove the create_function stuff that litters the theme they inherited, and add it so that there are no deprecations and the hooks can be used from the child theme? Right now that's not possible because of `create_function` and anonymous functions, hence my answer. The OP never asked how to unhook ( unhook != remove, one involves a `remove_action` call, the other involves code changes )

Comment: They didn't use the _word_ "unhook", sure, but "method to remove these actions and filters and properly add them in a child theme" describes the very common and normal process of unhooking actions via a child theme and re-adding them.  From the context of the question, including the mention of a child theme, it seemed apparent to me that editing the original theme was not what they are attempting to do.

Comment: It might be best to ask the clarifying question of the OP instead, afterall your interpretation does not account for the mentioned deprecations and `debug.log`

Comment: The function I posted in the initial question exists in the Parent theme. My intention is to bring this into the child theme and adjust the action. Now, I don't know if I can just copy it into the child theme with the same exact path and expect WP to override the theme's function, or if I'll get an error that this function already exists. I am aware of how to remove the warning, but was asking more so how to remove them from being used in the Parent theme. I know I can dequeue a script or style from the parent, but was wondering if there was a same method in WP to do this. I'll edit the OP

Comment: @NickM eh you can't just copy paste it into the child theme, that kind of override only works for temnplates. That also won't fix the deprecation issues you're seeing in `debug.log`. I've updated the answer accordingly

Comment: @TomJNowell While I understand this, I am not the original developer of the parent theme. Turns out due to all the errors of the `create_function` were done to create `sidebars`, copying and pasting it into the child theme with the correct file path and adjusting the action there did correct the errors. Though, since it is just registering sidebars, I could just remove the functions add_filter entirely and just register the sidebar in a separate hook.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out taking the following, and just removing `if ( ! function_exists( 'ot_register_theme_options_page' ) ) { }` and adjusting the filter will take priority over the parent theme.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'ot_register_theme_options_page' ) ) {

    function ot_register_theme_options_page() {

        /* get the settings array */
        $get_settings = _ut_theme_options();

        /* sections array */
        $sections = isset( $get_settings['sections'] ) ? $get_settings['sections'] : [];

        /* settings array */
        $settings = isset( $get_settings['settings'] ) ? $get_settings['settings'] : [];

        /* build the Theme Options */
        if ( function_exists( 'ot_register_settings' ) && OT_USE_THEME_OPTIONS ) {

            ot_register_settings(
                [
                    [
                        'id'    => 'option_tree',
                        'pages' => [
                            [
                                'id'              => 'ot_theme_options',
                                'parent_slug'     => apply_filters( 'ot_theme_options_parent_slug', 'unite-welcome-page' ),
                                'page_title'      => apply_filters( 'ot_theme_options_page_title', __( 'Theme Options', 'option-tree' ) ),
                                'menu_title'      => apply_filters( 'ot_theme_options_menu_title', __( 'Theme Options', 'option-tree' ) ),
                                'capability'      => $caps = apply_filters( 'ot_theme_options_capability', 'edit_theme_options' ),
                                'menu_slug'       => apply_filters( 'ot_theme_options_menu_slug', 'ut_theme_options' ),
                                'icon_url'        => apply_filters( 'ot_theme_options_icon_url', null ),
                                'position'        => apply_filters( 'ot_theme_options_position', null ),
                                'updated_message' => apply_filters( 'ot_theme_options_updated_message', __( 'Theme Options updated.', 'option-tree' ) ),
                                'reset_message'   => apply_filters( 'ot_theme_options_reset_message', __( 'Theme Options reset.', 'option-tree' ) ),
                                'button_text'     => apply_filters( 'ot_theme_options_button_text', __( 'Save Changes', 'option-tree' ) ),
                                'screen_icon'     => 'themes',
                                'sections'        => $sections,
                                'settings'        => $settings,
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ]
            );

            // Filters the options.php to add the minimum user capabilities.
            add_filter( 'option_page_capability_option_tree', create_function( '$caps', "return '$caps';" ), 999 );

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: That's not how that works. the child themes `functions.php` is loaded first, so this function gets defined first. Then, when the original code is run next, the function already exists, and since the function only gets defined if the function doesn't exist, it isn't defined. Nothing to do with child themes, just generic PHP. Note that this doesn't resolve PHP deprecation issues either